# Unintentionally copying argument

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to create an `AddItem` and `DeleteItem` function for my `array<Email, MAX_SIZE>`, called `ulist`.

The problem is, it's creating a local copy of the variable and adding that instead.

I'm new to pointers so it's probably a really simple mistake but it's been frustrating me for about an hour now.

Here is the code:

```
void UnsortedList::AddItem(Email &item)
{
    cout << "Going to add " << &item << endl;

    list[Length] = item;

    cout << "Added " << &list[Length] << endl;
    Length++;
}
```

From the driver:

```
Email e1("sender", "content");
UnsortedList ulist;
ulist.Add(e1);
```

Output:

```
Going to add 0018F6FC
Added 0018D09C
```

Comment: What's the type of `list`?

Comment: There is no pointer in your code, but you talk about pointers. Please study the posting guidelines, especially the part about the minimal but complete example code.

Comment: The character "&" means completely different things in types (a reference) and in expressions (the address-of operator). Do you want to have a collection of `Email`or of pointers to `Email`, i.e. `Email*`?

Comment: @Claudiu The type is `Email`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Ah, yes, the ritual "Read the guidelines" comment. No matter how many times I read that thing, someone is always here to tell me I didn't read it well enough. Classic StackOverflow.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't have a preference; whatever allows me to add and remove based on addresses/pointers/whatever the correct terminology is.

Comment: It doesn't happen to me nor do I feel compelled by everyone to tell them to RTFM. It's pretty unique though that you have the arrogance to respond like you were insulte. Also, at the same time you fixed part of what I told you made your question bad, while you ignored the rest of what others and I told you. Yes, it's likely that you are right and everybody else is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your `list` to store only pointers to the added items, declare it as a vector of pointers to `const Email`:

```
std::vector<const Email*> list;
```

Then, insert every new Email to the vector using its pointer:

```
void UnsortedList::AddItem(const Email &item) {
  list.push_back(&item);
}
```

But beware: you'll need to make sure in your program that the lifetime of the Email objects is longer than the lifetime of the list, otherwise the list will contain invalid pointers to deallocated objects.

Comment: Unfortunately do to the nature of this project it must be a standard array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `list` is an array of `Email`s... not an array of `Email *`s. So even though you pass an `Email &` into `AddItem`, the `Emai` gets copied on the assignment into `list`.

Instead you'll want something like:

```
array<Email *, MAX_LENGTH]> list;
```

And then on the assignment;

```
list[Length] = &item;
```

There's no other way around it. If the array doesn't store pointers, you will have to make a copy when you store into the array.